# Angular router won't navigate in http interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to redirect users to a login page if they are unauthenticated or their token has expired. My interceptor works properly, but the angular router isn't redirecting them. If I use window.location.href = "/login" then it works fine, but obviously this isn't the angular way and also causes my app to reload.
Here is my current http interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpRequest,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router ) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return this.authService.getSession().mergeMap(session => {
            if (session) {
                if (session.getIdToken().decodePayload().passwordExpired == 'true' && !this.router.url.includes('change-password')) {
                    // this navigation does not work
                    this.router.navigate(['/login/change-password'])
                } else if (request.url.includes(this.authService.awsUrl) || request.url.includes(this.authService.userUrl)) {
                    request = request.clone({
                        setHeaders: {
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${session.getIdToken().getJwtToken()}`
                        }
                    });
                }
                return next.handle(request);
            } else if (this.router.url.includes('login') || this.router.url.includes('provision')) {
                return next.handle(request);
            } else {
                //this navigation also does not work
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                return Observable.throw('token is not valid');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've also tried putting the navigation inside a method in my auth service, but that also does not work. Am I doing something wrong here? or am I just missing something small that is causing the router to hang? I'm on angular v6 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error in the console

Comment: Can you go step by step in debug mode and confirm that you reach the if section ?

Comment: No errors in the console, and I've confirmed that it is making it into the if section. My current code has window.location.href instead of router.navigate, and that works, but I don't like that it makes my app reload and is clearly not best practice.

Comment: are you calling this request from inside a router resolve?

Comment: Can you enable Route Tracing and paste the log? `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my opinion, this logic should be removed from the interceptor entirely.

Angular Router has build in Guard options protecting routes. See https://angular.io/guide/router#the-sample-application to view the different guard types.

With this, you can check for user authentication before a user is permitted to view a route, this is where the logic would go for your reroutes you are attempting based on your scenarios.

Once the user is authorized, they pass through to the desired route where the API calls will take place, which then pass through the interceptor and back to the component making the calls.

In short,

- Auth Guards should be used to validate and authorize users before they are permitted to view a route. If a user is unauthorized for any reason, reroute to the appropriate route.
- Interceptors should be used to modify HTTP calls before they leave the app and when they are first returned to the app. Here you would set your headers, modify endpoints through env variables, etc.

Comment: amen to that, very valid points, especially because he is concerned about the angular way

Comment: well if you already have a route open, leave the tab open and come back later, got deauthed in the mean time this interceptor will bring you back to the `/login` page.
But I too think that this shouldn't be implemented in the interceptor but extra.

Comment: Very valid point. I will refactor my app to redirect in a guard rather than this interceptor. What about in the case of a user being authenticated, sitting on the page, and their token expiring? It seems I would have to redirect from an interceptor in that case, but perhaps this problem won't happen If I try to navigate from an error interceptor

Comment: Routing from the interceptor is entirely possible, it should just be used lightly and only where necessary. You can watch the response type for 401 and redirect if unauthorized but core authentication logic should be in auth guards protecting locked down routes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to place router navigation, then you must place this code in tap function, 
for example:

```
return next.handle(tokenizedReq).pipe(
        tap({
          error: (res) => {    
            this.route.navigate(['/error'])
            console.log("tap, error", res);
          }
        }),
        catchError(this.errorHandler)  // this.errorHandler is a function
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

Some further information incase it helps someone that stumbles upon this problem in the future. I took the advice from the accepted answer and moved my redirect logic into an auth guard and an error interceptor, but even after the refactoring, `router.navigate(['/login'])` still wasn't working. I ended up realizing that the router was hanging due to my auth guard never resolving in the case of a user not being authenticated. After making the guard resolve the redirects worked perfectly.